# Running celery worker from inside the project

Tags: python, import, path, celery

I have an application which has the follow structure:

```
proj/
    __init__.py
    script1.py
    script2.py
    celery.py
    ...
```

The problem is that the project was initially written with the root directory inside the proj. I.e. import don't start with `import proj.script1` but are `import script1`. Now, if I try to start the worker from the directory above `proj`, it obviously messes things up. I tried adding `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` in `celery.py` with hopes to add the correct directory to the path but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround for me was to put `celery.py` inside another directory and then run worker while being in `proj/`.

Current directory structure:

```
proj/
    __init__.py
    script1.py
    script2.py
    Celery/
        celery.py
    ...
```

Not very beautiful but works.